# Js setTimeout() isn't working

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am making a snake game as you might have known from seeing my previous question. I am following up with just doing an array like this:

```
var snakeX = new Array();
var snakeY = new Array();
```

and then in a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0;i<=num;i++) {

    snakeX[0] = xCoord;

    snakeY[0] = yCoord;

    context.fillRect(snakeX[0], snakeY[0], sH, sW);

    xCoord = xCoord + 11;

    console.log('xCoord = ' + xCoord + ', yCoord = ' + yCoord);

}
```

and both the `xCoord` and `yCoord` vars are set to `0`.

My question is why isn't this working?

```
setInterval(function() {

    num++;  

}, 1000);
```

Here is everything I have:

```
function snake() {

    //Let's make the snake start at 4 squares wide, and 1 square tall

    function createSnake() {

        var xCoord = 0;

        var yCoord = 0;

        var snakeX = new Array();

        var snakeY = new Array();

        var num = 3;

        setInterval(function() {

            num = num + 1;  

        }, 1000);

        for (var i = 0;i<=num;i++) {

            snakeX[0] = xCoord;

            snakeY[0] = yCoord;

            context.fillRect(snakeX[0], snakeY[0], sH, sW);

            xCoord = xCoord + 11;

            console.log('xCoord = ' + xCoord + ', yCoord = ' + yCoord);

        }
    }
    createSnake();

}

snake();
```

Comment: `i <= num` should be `i < num`

Comment: What do you expect that the function passed to the interval timer will do?  It just increments that variable, but it does nothing to draw more snake.

Comment: What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: What it is supposed to do is increase the number at which the loop stops, so more squares of the snake appear. I don't know if that works or not, but I couldn't find anything else on how to do that...

Answer (score -1):

You never seem to be modifying `xCoord` and `yCoord`. Similarly, your "interval" is just increasing a number, it's not actually doing anything else. You need to have some kind of "redraw" function that moves the snake around. Also, you are creating `snakeX` and `snakeY` as arrays, but only ever using `snakeX[0]` and `snakeY[i]` - in fact, you aren't even using the `i` iterator.

Overall, it looks like your code is a bit of a trainwreck. Perhaps your project is a little ambitious for your current skill level, and you should work on some more basics before you attempt this. I'm not trying to discourage you by saying this, I'm just trying to offer some advice.

Comment: I'm modifying xCoord by doing `xCoord = xCoord + 11;`, and I'm positive I can do this. I have high hopes for it. It may not look good on the inside, but on the outside it will look good, and that's all I care about right now.

Comment: And I don't need to change the yCoord, because for now I just want all of the square to be on the top line.